# loading images from GPX file - iOS MapKit CS193 example

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, gpx

I'm following the example given in CS193p lecture 14 MapKit. I managed to load a gpx file (vacation.gpx that the lecturer used), but it only shows red pins and callouts without thumbnail and images when I click callouts.
In the original gpx file, all links work fine. How can I make it work? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

oops.. I found how to make it work.
I added this in the .plist to unblock http security.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```